# Vscode Extension: Hide menus contributions if extension is not active

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Vscode extensions are only activated if certain criteria are met. (Based on `activationEvents`).

In my extension, I want to add a menus contribution. Problem is, if the extension is not active, clicking the button will trigger an error. So ideally, it would only be visible if the extension is active.

How can I accomplish this? The `when-clause` seems too limited for that.

```
"activationEvents": [
    "workspaceContains:server"
],
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "extension.displayHelp",
            "title": "RCE Help"
        }
    ],      
    "menus": {
        "editor/title": [{
            "when": "resourceLangId != markdown",
            "command": "extension.displayHelp",
            "group": "navigation"
        }]
    },
}
```

[image]

---

Edit:

Turns out adding `onCommand` in the `activationEvents` works.

Even though Vscode states the command was not found in the error message, it did actually find it and decided to not trigger it.

```
"activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:extension.displayHelp",
    "workspaceContains:server",
],
```

However, I'd still prefer to hide the menu contribution entirely if the extension isn't active.

Comment: I have the same question, but I don't want to add the onCommand to activationEvents. If my activation events don't match, the commands will fail (lacking configuration information). It would be nice to not have contributions of inactive extensions show up or at least have the option.

Answer (score 0):

use like this code

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'yourCMD', true);

"menus": {
   "editor/context": [
      {
        "when": "editorHasSelection&&yourCMD",
         "command": "port.sendSelect",
          "group": "navigation"
       }
   ]
}
```

my code here https://github.com/hanfengcan/lemon